# Rsync changes folder and file names

Tags: linux, mac-osx, rsync, truenas

Folders that were initially created by a Mac computer, when rsynced the names get changed. The folder names contain a special character that looks like a normal dash "-", example:

1222017, it gets changed to PKM89E~Q

Any help would be mostly appreciated?

Comment: What rsync command are you using? Are you encapsulating the path with quotations?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/397420/converting-utf-8-nfd-filenames-to-utf-8-nfc-in-either-rsync-or-afpd/427200#427200

Comment: rsync -rvzs /source /destination. Source is a Windows server and destination is a freeBSD server